# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE only taking thumbnail

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475300/when-using-action-image-capture-why-is-the-preview-image-blurry) question recently, as I've been trying to use ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to take a picture in an app. I thought that it was just the preview that was small and square, but it seems that, even though I create a file, get a file:// uri, pass that in with EXTRA_OUTPUT, the photo that is taken and returned to me is a small, square thumbnail type image. I am using the GenyMotion simulator and the camera app is the stock android one. I have verified that the file is correctly created and the uri that is passed in is a file:// uri pointing to the file that is created.

Dispatch the intent:

```
private void dispatchPhotoIntent() throws
   IOException
{
   Intent photo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   if(photo.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null &&
      checkWritePermissions() == true) {
      File receipt = makeReceiptFile();
      receiptUri = Uri.fromFile(receipt);
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Uri is " + receiptUri.toString());
      photo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, receiptUri);
      startActivityForResult(photo, GET_PHOTO);
   }
}
```

Get the result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result,
                                Intent data)
{
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Starting result");
   if(request == GET_PHOTO &&
      result  == RESULT_OK &&
      data    != null) {
      String path    = receiptUri.getPath();
      Bitmap receipt = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
      new PostProcessImage().execute(receipt);
   }
}
```

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same as for your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475300/when-using-action-image-capture-why-is-the-preview-image-blurry). Whatever Genymotion is using for a camera app, when combined with your webcam, is delivering poor results. There is not much you can do about that, other than realize that you are testing a scenario (Genymotion+webcam) that ~0.0% of your users will be using.

Comment: This doesn't make sense; When the camera app shows the live preview of the photograph, it is full quality. It is only when the photo is taken that it is converted to a format that is obviously meant to be a thumbnail.

Comment: Then contact Genymotion for support with their camera app. Or, better yet, stop using an emulator for testing camera support, and instead test on a few actual Android devices (ideally from a mix of manufacturers, and not all Nexus devices).